# Finding the cumulative distribution function of the sum of two functions of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

Since we want two real roots, then we're looking for a positive discriminant.

Let $Z$ be the random variable representing the value taken by the discriminant.

So, 
$$Z = 4(U^2 - V)$$

However, I don't know where to take it from here.

Any Hints would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We want to find $\mathbb P(Z>0)$, or $\mathbb P(U^2>V)$. For $0<t<1$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(U^2\leqslant t) = \mathbb P(U\leqslant t^{\frac12}) = t^{\frac12}
$$
and so $U^2$ has density
$$
f(t) = \frac12 t^{-\frac12}\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t).
$$
We know already that $V$ has density $g(t) = \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t)$, so integrating over the joint density we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(U^2>V) &= \int_0^1 \int_t^1 \frac12 s^{-\frac12} \ \mathsf ds\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-t^{\frac12})\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac13.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$P\{U^{2} >V\}=EP(\{U^{2} >V\}|U\})=EU^{2}=\int _0^{1} u^{2}\, du =\frac 1 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The positive discriminant implies $Z=4(U^2-V)>0$, hence you need to find $\mathbb P(U^2-V>0)$. Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

The required probability is the green area:
$$\mathbb P(U^2-V>0)=\mathbb P(V<U^2)=\int_0^1 U^2 dU=\frac{U^3}{3}\bigg{|}_0^1=\frac13.$$